# StatusStrip cross-threading error

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have went over my code and put in invokers which is working pretty good until this part:

```
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
{
    statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    statusLabel.Text = "Pausing...";
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;    
}));
```

I have a "statusStrip" and within this i have a "statusLabel" i'm getting a cross-thread error on the "statusStrip" i never access the "statusStrip" only the "statusLabel.text" part, am i doing soemthing wrong here?

Comment: If you're getting an error about accessing `statusStrip`, this isn't the code causing you problems. Where are you actually accessing `statusStrip`?

Comment: What is the actual exception, which line throws it? Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you are freezing the UI thread for 10 seconds, what error are you getting, exactly? What is the exception text, including its stacktrace?